# What means the modular operator in that proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, discrete-geometry

I need to understand a proof of a lemma about the Illumination Problem in Euclidian Space; the proof's author is George Tokarsky (1991). See the images below. Can you help me understand?

[Proof 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udcDa.jpg)

[Proof 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36CO7.jpg)

1. I know that $a \mod b$ is equal to the rest of the division $a/b$.
2. I know that $a \equiv c \mod b$ is equivalent to say $a \mod b = c \mod b$

I have the next questions:

- What means "We measure all angles $\mod 2x$"?

Following $(1)$:

What represent here $a$?

There is $b$? What represent?

Why $2x$ and no $x$ or other coefficient?

- What means $\theta \equiv 90 \mod 2x$?
- What means $\theta \equiv 0 \mod x$?

Thank you!

Comment: This apparently means angle measure is an element of the quotient $\mathbf R/2x\mathbf Z$. Usually in mathematics, angles have a measure in $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$. So $\theta\equiv 90\mod 2x$ means $\theta=90+2kx$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$. It's hard to say more, as we don't know what $x$ is;

Answer (score 1):

In the triangle shown, all edges slopes are at multiples of $x$ relative to the base line, hence  an input angle $\alpha$ is reflected into an even multiple of $x$ minus $\alpha$, hence at each reflection, $\pm\theta+2kx$ becomes $\mp\theta +2k'x$. As we start with $\theta+ 0x$, we will by induction always travel at some $\pm \theta +2kx$, i.e., at an angle that is $\equiv \pm\theta \pmod{2x}$